# Do I need to use an API to create an Android app that will direct to a radio station web site?

Tags: android

I am building an Android mobile application which will be coded to direct itself to a web site for a single radio station. Will it open and play what is on the station by coding the url into the app, or do I need an API? If so, where can I find one to use and possibly information about integrating it into the app?

Comment: Please, ask more specific questions.

Comment: By Crom, please stop making Android apps that simply wrap a few URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webView to open your website url in the activity